# Thread in Qt doesn't work correctly

Tags: qt

i have a qt app with a thread beside the main.
thread starts when a button is clicked:
in the main:

```
void MainWindow::on_Start_Sampling_clicked()
{  My_drawing_object1->start();}
```

and in thread:

```
#include "my_drawing_object.h"

#include <QDebug>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QTimer>
My_drawing_object::My_drawing_object(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
}

My_drawing_object::~My_drawing_object()
{
}
int timer_shot_num=0;
QTimer *timer = new QTimer;

void My_drawing_object::start()
{
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(Draw_new_set_of_Data()));
    timer->start(10);
}

void My_drawing_object::Draw_new_set_of_Data(){
    // logic sample points
    timer_shot_num++;
    if (timer_shot_num==1){
        timer->stop();
        timer_shot_num=0;
    }
....
```

what i Expect is that for each button click,the tread should run once.but in the first click it runs once,at the second click it runs 2 times, in the third click it runs 3 times....
why?

Comment: You create a new connection every time `My_drawing_object::start()` is called. Move your `connect` statement somewhere else, like the constructor. You might as well make `timer` a member of your `My_drawing_object` class. I don't know why you are using global variables here.

Comment: as thuga mentioned, the connect will get executed everytime. Just make the connect during constructor (prefered) or add `Qt::UniqueuConnection`. Nevertheless I do not see any threading in your example.

Comment: You might be surprised, but threads in Qt *do* work correctly, when you use them correctly.  You need to make your question title more accurate and more descriptive.

Comment: Also you might want to have a look to `QTimer::singleShot()`. It might be an alternative to the "connect()/start()" calls.

Comment: You are not working with _threads_ but rather with _timers_. "thread" should be changed into "timer" everywhere in your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consecutive `connect` operations cause the events to occur more than they ought to when their signal is fired. You should either first `disconnect` the repeating slot after some operation is done, or make sure that `connect` code runs only once (such as, in a constructor). I mean, do not place the `connect` action into repeatable code blocks.

Answer (score 0):

In your connect calls, you can also specify Qt::UniqueConnection as the connection type; this ensures that a given connection between the same signal and slots of two objects is never duplicated. I also agree with the above that it's better to get the connections made in a constructor or other location where they're not called repeatedly. However, it's occasionally inconvenient or messy to do that, especially when the connections are made by a third class, and the UniqueConnection option handles that nicely.